# C# Console Error: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, console

I am new to programming and am attempting to learn c#. I am having what i think is a simple problem with my console application(the code is below). The error appears to be with my if statement which reads as follows:

```
//evaluate subtotals to results
        if (subTotalOne == subTotalTwo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("=");
        }
        else if (subTotalOne < subTotalTwo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("<");
        }
        else (subTotalOne > subTotalTwo);
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(">"); 
        }
```

The error i get is: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

Any help would be appreciated. I have read through the forums here and seen may similar questions but my understanding isn't good enough yet to map the solutions i've seen to my problem.

Full application code:

```
using System;
```

namespace itc110_a02_GroceryComparison
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

```
        Console.WriteLine("Compare Grocery Stores "); //Alert user to purpose of program with title
        Console.WriteLine("\n");//line break



        // Store 1
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of the first store for comparison: ");//storeName 1
        String storeOne = Console.ReadLine();//ToLower for eval

        //store 1, first item
        Console.WriteLine("Name of First product purchased at " + storeOne + ": ");//ask item
        String purchaseOne = Console.ReadLine();//collect item
        Console.WriteLine("Price paid for first purchased at " + storeOne + ": ");//ask 1st price
        Double price1A = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());//collect 1st price

        //store 1, second item, repeat process -- this ought to be a method or a function
        Console.WriteLine("Name of second product purchased at " + storeOne + ": ");//ask item
        String purchaseTwo = Console.ReadLine();//collect Item
        Console.WriteLine("Price paid for second purchased at " + storeOne + ": ");//Ask Item Price
        Double price1B = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());//Collect Item Price
        Console.WriteLine("\n");



        // Store 2, repeat process -- this ought to be a method or a function
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of the second store for comparison: ");//Store name 1
        String storeTwo = Console.ReadLine();// To Evals entry, we  ToLower to set to lower case

        //store 2
        Console.WriteLine("Price paid for " + purchaseOne + " at " + storeTwo + ": ");//ask 1st price
        Double price2A = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());//collect 1st price

        //store 2, second item
        Console.WriteLine("Price paid for " + purchaseTwo + " at " + storeTwo + ": ");//Ask Item Price
        Double price2B = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());//Collect Item Price
        Console.WriteLine("\n");



        // Results go here
        //Store one totals
        Console.WriteLine("************  " + storeOne + "  ************");
        Console.WriteLine(purchaseOne + ": $" + price1A);
        Console.WriteLine(purchaseTwo + ": $" + price1B);
        Console.WriteLine("\n \n");
        // store two totals
        Console.WriteLine("************  " + storeTwo + "  ************");
        // Result A: Where to shop
        Console.WriteLine(purchaseOne + ": $" + price2A);
        Console.WriteLine(purchaseTwo + ": $" + price2B);
        Console.WriteLine("\n \n");

        Console.WriteLine("************  After Price Comparison  ************");



        //merge subtotals
        Double subTotalOne = (price1A + price1B);
        Double subTotalTwo = (price2A + price2B);



        //evaluate subtotals to results
        if (subTotalOne == subTotalTwo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("=");
        }
        else if (subTotalOne < subTotalTwo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("<");
        }
        else (subTotalOne > subTotalTwo);
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(">"); 
        }            



        //keeps the console open
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You might want to use `string` and `double` instead of `String` and `Double` to declare your variables.

Comment: @Tico - Really..?? And how this will solve the error?

Comment: @Rohit Vats I didn't say neither imply that it will solve the error. It's just good practices. Calm down...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `else` line is the problem.

```
    else (subTotalOne > subTotalTwo);
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(">"); 
    }
```

Fixed:

```
    else
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(">"); 
    }
```

Explanation:

Your code is equivalent to:

```
else
   (subTotalOne > subTotalTwo);//else block

{ 
    Console.WriteLine(">"); 
}
```

semicolon makes the condition expression as statement and so the error. 
However, the next console statement will also not be part of else block as the else block finishes after semicolon. So, even if the condition expression was a valid statement, ">" will always be printed which is not desired.

Comment: Technically, if one of the two comparands was `double.NaN`, it wouldn't be the same to have just `else` instead of `else if (subTotalOne > subTotalTwo)`. But this is a minor detail here.

Comment: Thank you to everyone for their suggestions and guidance, all of which I promise that I have read and after I go for a short walk to consider everything that has been said, will re-read again. My program is working now and I thank you all for your wonderful help. I know this is a simple thing, and I thank everyone for showing me how to make it simpler. I have lots still to learn and I thank you all (did i say thank you enough?)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably going for:

```
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(">");
}
```

since you have eliminated all other possibilities.

On a formatting front I have never been a fan of else if all one line. For beginners especially, it can obscure program flow.  There are others who completely disagree with me though...